# generic regex to capture various optional groups

Tags: c#, regex, regex-group

I am looking for a method to select, using regex, lines containing various groups, some of them optional, and capture the groups - the found ones, of course. After reading here on stackoverflow and many experiments I came up with this general enough approach:

```
^(?:.*?(aaa).*?|.*?)(xxx).*?(yyy)(?:.*?([^ \n]+).*?|.*?)$
```

So the general term for optional groups is:

```
(?:.*?(blabla).*?|.*?)
```

The above approach has backtracking problems in case of:

- large texts;
- when nothing is match;
- when there are only optional groups.

Any ideea how to create a generic enough regex able to capture optional groups? By generic I mean, like in the example I found, easily scalable up for various group patterns.
Thanks.

Comment: Hi. Please include a tag for one specific engine or language (perl, pcre, c#, etc…). Regular expression questions get better answers if they… show the pattern that isn't working, **provide some examples of input text that should match, and also ones that shouldn't match**. Describe the desired results, and how the pattern isn't producing them.

Comment: Both of these [fail with catastrophic backtracking](https://regex101.com/r/qK0v2d/2/) on regex101.com with a few paragraphs of text. The reason isn't hard to figure out, what with your eight different `.*` wildcards, imagine all the possible permutations of eight different things that can all be anything or nothing...

Comment: @sweaver2112 Yes, there are problems:
- with large texts;
- when in the pattern are only optional groups;
- when nothing is matched.
This can be alleviated by using a two steps approach and first using a pattern which does not contain the optional groups. And fortunately, I have to search in relatively short lines.

Comment: If the actual problem is, why the second pattern doesn't capture the `bbbaaa` sequence: because the `.*?` after yyy does not advance the position and therefore it cannot continue the pattern since there is space: Try it like this: [`^.*?(?:(aaa)|.*?).*?(xxx).*?(yyy)(?:(.*?)([^ \n]+)|.*?).*?$`](https://regex101.com/r/7KJmSA/1). I've added capture group 4 for demonstration purpose only.

Comment: I wonder, why writing `(?:(aaa)|.*?)` when you could just write `(?:(aaa)?)`?. So, if you don't have `(aaa)`, then your expression turns into `.*?.*?` which is a nonsense.

Comment: @JohnyL If you try the pattern ^.*?((aaa)?).*?$ on regex101.com you will see that does not capture.

Comment: @sweaver2112 I realized that if I avoid sequences like .*?.*? I get an improvement. So I have used ^(?:.*?(aaa).*?|.*?)(bbb)(?:.*?([^\s0-9]+).*?|.*?)$ in your example.
https://regex101.com/r/qK0v2d/3

Answer (score 0):

A more strikt approach could solve the issue. Instead of .*? we use a tempered greedy token that allows everything but the optional search term:

```
^(?:(?!bla).)*(bla)?(?:(?!bla).)*$
```

[**Demo**](https://regex101.com/r/Zl7B2Y/1)

This performs much better than the original approach (even on [large text](https://regex101.com/r/37y6Ir/1)) and still easy to extend and maintain; e.g. you can add additional restricted terms to the tempered token with alternations:

```
(?:(?!bla|blub).)*(bla|blub)?(?:(?!bla|blub).)*
```

[**Demo**](https://regex101.com/r/dS5oJE/1) (Note: the start/end anchor were removed)

This [rexegg.com tutorial](https://www.rexegg.com/regex-quantifiers.html#tempered_greed) explains pretty much everything about the greedy token and shows possible variations.

[Code Sample](https://ideone.com/rCo7e1)

Comment: It does not seem to work. Could you show me an example for two capturing groups?

Comment: @Gigi I pull the answer since I am busy and cannot check it right now but come back to it later today.

Comment: I am looking for a solution for the case when also the order of the optional groups is relevant. I have tried with no success:
(?:(?!bla).)*(bla)?(?:(?!bla).)*.*?(?:(?!blub).)*(blub)?(?:(?!blub).)*
It may also be the case that there are repetitions, meaning I have to search for a series of optional groups like: aaa, aaa, bbb, aaa. I know, in such case, when one or more of the groups is/are missing, is hard to tell which is which but that's another problem.